from redis.commands.search.field import TagField, TextField, VectorField ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis.commands' ERROR
from redis.commands.search.field import TagField, TextField, VectorField
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis.commands'
i have the above - and am using redis                     3.5.3
how can i recitfy this?

You need redis=5.0.8 for using redis.commands at least. But if you will use redisearch for querying to db it's conflicts with depended redis version. so please update at your own risk ‍♂️
